# Can anyone please provide me a proof,directly or a link for Ptolemy's Second Theorem? Maybe it is also known as Mahavira's Result.

Tags: reference-request

I referred to website www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/ptolemy.shtml and www.mathafou.free.fr/themes_en/kptol.html but the material was not satisfactory and a little complicatedly represented. Thank you!

Comment: Explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer here at the link given below:

[Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral with side lengths $AB=p,BC=q,CD=r,DA=s$.Show that $\dfrac{AC}{BD}=\dfrac{ps+qr}{pq+rs}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651993/let-abcd-be-a-cyclic-quadrilateral-with-side-lengths-ab-p-bc-q-cd-r-da-s-sho)

Good Luck!

Comment: Though the link you provided is from my question...but it is correct! Thanks anyway.