# A cyclic quadrilateral with ratios

Tags: geometry

Quadrilateral $ABCD$ is cyclic, with $BC=BD=1$. If $AD:AC:AB=1:7:5$, then find $AD^2$. I tried applying Ptolemy's theorem, I got $CD$, and then some angles but it did not give me something.

Comment: If you got CD, than the rest should be easy... I think.

Comment: How? What should I do then?

Comment: Did you try Heron's formula for triangle area?

Comment: Did you try this? - If ABCD  is a cyclic quadrilateral, then AC⋅(AB⋅BC+CD⋅DA)=BD⋅(DA⋅AB+BC⋅CD)

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get this result? Also, from this I am getting the answer 6/192, could you check, where is it wrong?

Comment: I just found another question that suggest this property. Look to the right of the comments at the "Related" section.

Comment: @garvil where do you get all these questions about cyclic quadrilaterals?

Comment: I am getting CD = 1.2 and from here: 0.1768

Comment: Please, fractions. I also got the same value of $CD$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AD=x=\frac{AC}{7}=\frac{AB}{5}$. Then according to Ptolemy's theorem, $1(7x)=1(x)+(CD)(5x)$, which gives $CD=\frac{6}{5}$. Now let the midpoint of $CD$ be $M$. We see that $\cos\angle CAB=\cos\angle CDB=\frac{DM}{BD}=\frac{3}{5}$, and then it follows from the law of Cosines on triangle $ABC$ that:
$$(5x)^2+(7x)^2-2(7x)(5x)(\frac{3}{5})=1^2\implies x^2=\boxed{\frac{1}{32}}$$[image: Geo Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Ptolemy's theorem to get CD: $(5x)(CD) + (1)(x) = (1)(7x)$, $CD = 1.2$

Then just apply diagonal ratios formula from this link.
[Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral with side lengths $AB=p,BC=q,CD=r,DA=s$.Show that $\dfrac{AC}{BD}=\dfrac{ps+qr}{pq+rs}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651993/let-abcd-be-a-cyclic-quadrilateral-with-side-lengths-ab-p-bc-q-cd-r-da-s-sho?rq=1)

For this problem, $p=5x$, $q=1$, $r=1.2$, $s=x$

$$\frac{AC}{BD} = \frac{7x}{1} = \frac{5 x^2 + 1.2}{5x + 1.2x}$$

$$43.4 x^2 = 5 x^2 + 1.2  $$
$$x^2 = \frac{1.2}{43.4-5} = 0.03125 = \frac{1}{32}$$